# Golf an Advent Calendar

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

It's that time of year when many of us get our [advent calendars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advent_calendar)! If you are unfamiliar with an advent calendar, these are  special calendars used to count down advent in anticipation of Christmas. In my experience the doors are placed randomly, and part of the fun as a child was working out where tomorrow's door was! Often these days, calendars have chocolates behind each door, but instead of buying an advent calendar this year, you should build an ASCII one!

### Task

Given input of an integer (`n`) in the range `0`-`24`, produce an ASCII advent calendar with the numbered doors up-to `n`, opened. You must use the same order as in the below example: `2`, `17`, `8`, `12`, `1`, `6`, `11`, `20`, `5`, `22`, `3`, `10`, `15`, `23`, `7`, `16`, `9`, `24`, `18`, `4`, `13`, `19`, `21`, `14`.

### Doors

The closed door must be:

```
.-----------.
|           |
|           |
|           |
|       nn  |
|___________|
```

where `n` represents the number of the door (leading zeros are optional) and the opened door is:

```
.-----------.
|\          |
| |         |
| |         |
| |         |
| |_________|
 \|
```

except for door 24, which is instead:

```
.--------------------------.
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                      24  |
|__________________________|
.--------------------------.
|\                         |
| |                        |
| |                        |
| |                        |
| |________________________|
 \|
```

These doors are arranged within a frame of 37 lines of 79 characters, with two spaces between each column, and an empty line between each row.

### Opened Doors

When the doors are opened you must display one of the (tenuously Christmas related - apologies for my terrible art skills!) pictures below within the door:

```
 . _ .    _'_        +       .^o     _(")_     _n_       $        .     
 }\O/{    ) (^.^_   /~\     (';')   (_ . _)    (")      |,|    __/ \__  
 }/*\{    \./v`v'  /~*~\   {\|+|/}   / : \   >( o )<    | |    `.   .'  
 /***\     oO8    /~*~~*\    d-b    (_/ \_)  (  o  )  ._|_|_.   /.^.\   

 .\^/.     ____   __.==,_    .*.     _   _    . . .   _______   _   _   
<->o<->   /_%_/|  --|XX|-    /.\    (O X O)  .i_i_i.  _j_j_j_  ( `v' )  
 '/v\`   |_|_| |   _|  |    |_-_|    / ^ \   |-~~-~|   ||__|    \   /   
         |_|_|/   (____'   (.-o-.)   \/ \/   |_____|  _|/$$|_     V     

   i       |~|     //'`\     |=|    _{/ _{/   ,   *   \  ====     b     
 .'%'.     | |    //....\    / \      \_/    +  . +   \\\|+-|   .'''.   
|^~~.~|     Y     ||()()|   |(%)|     /O \     . ' .  \\\\\+|  {*=*=*}  
_'._.'_    _|_    ||_[]_|   |___|   @__,/\\  ~~~~~~~  \\\\\\\   '._.'   

    _    |  _  |  .W. .W.  .&%$+*.    \O/       .;'   ..,.;..   ('v')    
  .'.'O  | ($) |  |*| |*|  */'"'\&  [ ]|_.     .m_.   |\\|//|  //   \\   
 /___\   |  " o|  |*| |*|  $\._./%  |_____)   C|  |    \\|//   |\   /|   
(_____)  | === |  'M' 'M'  '%&*+$'  ------'    |__|    _=|=_     Y Y    

 \   /      .==.    .-.     -._.-   __/\__     ...       .-.   
._o_O_.  .--'  |  \|   |/    .+.    \_\/_/    '*  `     //`);  
|/\/\/|  \_____/  /|   |\   ( W )   /_/\_\   |_/\*_|   %%      
"""""""  `====='    '-'      `"`      \/     [_____]  //
```

Each image is 7 characters long and covers 4 lines so they will fit within the windows. You are free to choose any of the  above images and use them in any order, but  you may not repeat an image. For the 24th, you must also add a message:

```
       ~       
   ~ MERRY ~   
 ~ CHRISTMAS! ~
     ~~~~~
```

which fits alongside one of the above pictures, you can choose whether the text is to the right or the left of the image.

### Examples

Given input `0`, output the calendar with no doors opened:

```
.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |        2  |  |       17  |  |        8  |  |       12  |  |        1  |  |
|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |
|                                                                             |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |        6  |  |       11  |  |       20  |  |        5  |  |       22  |  |
|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |
|                                                                             |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |        3  |  |       10  |  |       15  |  |       23  |  |        7  |  |
|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |
|                                                                             |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .--------------------------.  .-----------.  |
|  |           |  |           |  |                          |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |                          |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |                          |  |           |  |
|  |       16  |  |        9  |  |                      24  |  |       18  |  |
|  |___________|  |___________|  |__________________________|  |___________|  |
|                                                                             |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  |        4  |  |       13  |  |       19  |  |       21  |  |       14  |  |
|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |
|                                                                             |
|_____________________________________________________________________________|
```

For input `5`, output something similar to:

```
.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\   . _ .  |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |\  __.==,_ |  |
|  | |  }\O/{  |  |           |  |           |  |           |  | | --|XX|- |  |
|  | |  }/*\{  |  |           |  |           |  |           |  | |  _|  |  |  |
|  | |  /***\  |  |       17  |  |        8  |  |       12  |  | | (____'  |  |
|  | |_________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  | |_________|  |
|   \|                                                          \|            |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  |\  _{/ _{/ |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  | |   \_/   |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |           |  | |   /O \  |  |           |  |
|  |        6  |  |       11  |  |       20  |  | | @__,/\\ |  |       22  |  |
|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  | |_________|  |___________|  |
|                                                \|                           |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\    _n_   |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  | |   (")   |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  | | >( o )< |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  | | (  o  ) |  |       10  |  |       15  |  |       23  |  |        7  |  |
|  | |_________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |
|   \|                                                                        |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .--------------------------.  .-----------.  |
|  |           |  |           |  |                          |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |                          |  |           |  |
|  |           |  |           |  |                          |  |           |  |
|  |       16  |  |        9  |  |                      24  |  |       18  |  |
|  |___________|  |___________|  |__________________________|  |___________|  |
|                                                                             |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\     +    |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  | |   /~\   |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  | |  /~*~\  |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |           |  |
|  | | /~*~~*\ |  |       13  |  |       19  |  |       21  |  |       14  |  |
|  | |_________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |___________|  |
|   \|                                                                        |
|_____________________________________________________________________________|
```

For input `14`:

```
.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\   . _ .  |  |           |  |\     .    |  |\    ____  |  |\  __.==,_ |  |
|  | |  }\O/{  |  |           |  | | __/ \__ |  | |  /_%_/| |  | | --|XX|- |  |
|  | |  }/*\{  |  |           |  | | `.   .' |  | | |_|_| | |  | |  _|  |  |  |
|  | |  /***\  |  |       17  |  | |  /.^.\  |  | | |_|_|/  |  | | (____'  |  |
|  | |_________|  |___________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  |
|   \|                            \|             \|             \|            |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\      _   |  |\     $    |  |           |  |\  _{/ _{/ |  |           |  |
|  | |   .'.'O |  | |   |,|   |  |           |  | |   \_/   |  |           |  |
|  | |  /___\  |  | |   | |   |  |           |  | |   /O \  |  |           |  |
|  | | (_____) |  | | ._|_|_. |  |       20  |  | | @__,/\\ |  |       22  |  |
|  | |_________|  | |_________|  |___________|  | |_________|  |___________|  |
|   \|             \|                            \|                           |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\    _n_   |  |\   _(")_  |  |           |  |           |  |\    |=|   |  |
|  | |   (")   |  | | (_ . _) |  |           |  |           |  | |   / \   |  |
|  | | >( o )< |  | |  / : \  |  |           |  |           |  | |  |(%)|  |  |
|  | | (  o  ) |  | | (_/ \_) |  |       15  |  |       23  |  | |  |___|  |  |
|  | |_________|  | |_________|  |___________|  |___________|  | |_________|  |
|   \|             \|                                           \|            |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .--------------------------.  .-----------.  |
|  |           |  |\  \  ==== |  |                          |  |           |  |
|  |           |  | | \\\|--| |  |                          |  |           |  |
|  |           |  | | \\\\\-| |  |                          |  |           |  |
|  |       16  |  | | \\\\\\\ |  |                      24  |  |       18  |  |
|  |___________|  | |_________|  |__________________________|  |___________|  |
|                  \|                                                         |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\     +    |  |\    ,  *  |  |           |  |           |  |\     i    |  |
|  | |   /~\   |  | | +  .  + |  |           |  |           |  | |  .'%'.  |  |
|  | |  /~*~\  |  | |  .  ' . |  |           |  |           |  | | |^~~.~| |  |
|  | | /~*~~*\ |  | | ~~~~~~~ |  |       19  |  |       21  |  | | _'._.'_ |  |
|  | |_________|  | |_________|  |___________|  |___________|  | |_________|  |
|   \|             \|                                           \|            |
|_____________________________________________________________________________|
```

For input `24`:

```
.-----------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\   . _ .  |  |\   //''\  |  |\     .    |  |\    ____  |  |\  __.==,_ |  |
|  | |  }\O/{  |  | | //....\ |  | | __/ \__ |  | |  /_%_/| |  | | --|XX|- |  |
|  | |  }/*\{  |  | | ||()()| |  | | `.   .' |  | | |_|_| | |  | |  _|  |  |  |
|  | |  /***\  |  | | ||_[]_| |  | |  /.^.\  |  | | |_|_|/  |  | | (____'  |  |
|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  |
|   \|             \|             \|             \|             \|            |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\      _   |  |\     $    |  |\    |~|   |  |\  _{/ _{/ |  |\   . . .  |  |
|  | |   .'.'O |  | |   |,|   |  | |   | |   |  | |   \_/   |  | | .i_i_i. |  |
|  | |  /___\  |  | |   | |   |  | |    Y    |  | |   /O \  |  | | |-~~-~| |  |
|  | | (_____) |  | | ._|_|_. |  | |   _|_   |  | | @__,/\\ |  | | |_____| |  |
|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  |
|   \|             \|             \|             \|             \|            |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\    _n_   |  |\   _(")_  |  |\  |  _  | |  |\  .W. .W. |  |\    |=|   |  |
|  | |   (")   |  | | (_ . _) |  | | | ($) | |  | | |*| |*| |  | |   / \   |  |
|  | | >( o )< |  | |  / : \  |  | | |  " o| |  | | |*| |*| |  | |  |(%)|  |  |
|  | | (  o  ) |  | | (_/ \_) |  | | | === | |  | | 'M' 'M' |  | |  |___|  |  |
|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  |
|   \|             \|             \|             \|             \|            |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .--------------------------   .-----------.  |
|  |\   _   _  |  |\  \  ==== |  |\  .&%$+*.       ~        |  |\    \O/   |  |
|  | | (O X O) |  | | \\\|--| |  | | */'"'\&   ~ MERRY ~    |  | | [ ]|_.  |  |
|  | |  / ^ \  |  | | \\\\\-| |  | | $\._./% ~ CHRISTMAS! ~ |  | | |_____) |  |
|  | |  \/ \/  |  | | \\\\\\\ |  | | '%&*+$'     ~~~~~      |  | | ------' |  |
|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |________________________|  | |_________|  |
|   \|             \|             \|                            \|            |
|  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  .-----------.  |
|  |\     +    |  |\   ,   *  |  |\     |    |  |\    .*.   |  |\     i    |  |
|  | |   /~\   |  | | +  . +  |  | |  .'''.  |  | |   /.\   |  | |  .'%'.  |  |
|  | |  /~*~\  |  | |   . ' . |  | | {*=*=*} |  | |  |_-_|  |  | | |^~~.~| |  |
|  | | /~*~~*\ |  | | ~~~~~~~ |  | |  '._.'  |  | | (.-o-.) |  | | _'._.'_ |  |
|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  | |_________|  |
|   \|             \|             \|             \|             \|            |
|_____________________________________________________________________________|
```

### Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes, in each language, wins.

- Any reasonable format can be used for I/O assuming it is consistent.
- Any amount of whitespace before and after the calendar is fine, as well as additional spaces/unprintables at the end of each line, but nothing before each line as this must fit into 80 characters.
- All [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/9365) are forbidden.

### Thanks

[James Holderness](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62101/james-holderness) for contributing ASCII images!

Comment: This is so cute!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>676 639 614 607 598 590 564</strike> 561 bytes

```
Ｐ⁴⁰↓.↓³⁷Ｍ↗×³⁹_‖ＯＦ²⁴«≔⌕”%↖∧F◨℅V⊖⎚λJ↷;φε⊟ ↧”§βιε≔⎇⁼²³ι²⁶⊕χαＪ×﹪ε⁵¦¹⁵×÷ε⁵¦⁷Ｍ³¦².α↓.↓⁵↖←×⁻α²_¿‹ιＩθ«Ｍ±¹±⁴↘¹↓⁵↖↖\↑⁵Ｍ⁴¦¹ＥＥ⁴⁺×﹪ι⁸¦⁷×⁵⁶⁺κ×⁴÷ι⁸✂”}⊞r⌕⁸⸿‹;β/｜∧±⪪Ｉ÷=EＥ%±÷ü5>ü⊘-▶⁹⦃vy⌈#$“o⊟ⅈ‖zＭq‖s0ＹV↔↔|⎈⁹'⁸γ₂βxM¿yH⌕.➙↧↘⁻³]υ｜tψ⧴À‹>8Φπ；Ｖ}Ｑλjgd↔⟲｜WU(‖Ｊ⁴⁹ＸJx#aα➙?⁰Ｎ@⁵=πＸ⭆›*≡ηΦzgQ±tJ;∨≦K⪫9⁸πcω2-0CγＮ8｜x43,ＢＤua←A9Ｍ№»⎚‴dＮ|k9<·⊖Ｒ?Ｔρe»∧=₂₂~⁰i³e4⮌↖λ″ＯÞν%≧Jj◧ＳLÀ·Π_B₂Ｔσ-*¬y&XWP›J↔À≕²ψＴ↘b▶“ζX↙ΣψSCμ#×Ｉ？Ｋ%Ｈ6Ｋⅉ⁸OＨ…⁸Ｕⅈ«j×⟦χ～gＰ% ¦◨⦄⟲24；⦄▷Ｙ>≕À▶；DψＪψＹＮ(Ｎ-⊞Ｋ‹▷⦃Ug∧⦃8⊕|·ＨＯ；ＪＺ⎇*>GPＭ⮌Σ�“Ｐ²⁼↶w66›λ⁼±⧴ι⊟uβρ⁻C⊙Ｚ+%oΣＶＬtＹ1Ｏ≦ O｜ηf±h﹪φ⊟”¦κ⁺κ⁷Ｍ⁸±⁴¿⁼²³ι”¶<↑?≡ＤTh¤WSＷV～≔✂r₂b…wＳεGl≔TêE¶(…Ｒ↘�”»«←__↑⁵Ｍ⁻α²¦⁴←⮌Ｉ⊕ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVTtThNBFH0VEqwaFFREAkFARdSgRgwK/tA0iAoiCRFBgYDZRVi2DSEYoQWtrZ9bbBXd7cd22yEks/9n3@G@wDwCnqkYTXY7na97zz33nB0aGZwYGh8c29@X7BfpedJ/kfGmAS/Pke5K9oOMuB9XEy9MWkyyn5JZ3MFRnqXIOq1skPY@REaMzPQlim/T4lI/RWO0@lZUeshw2wJDFCiaqiEjjZM8LRzhYQVXV5dJZ9zhOeGpgEWKbgTLwpYs48ell8EhvcAt7mHw4757MP@Diuew4zQI@wAtthQGY82Pk14RNnfCfI80T3iSfRMlnlV3bO5xWxVpbCLqv0uxu2S8xkRVi7qQUrKveKp8lP@AAYpSNblKUFBo9bIoq0ke0NQuJRZQ4DxFkxOKFSyUFII24ZyQuwnQg9yZDOD4bns3ooe47bs@O9PhM4pu1lMMIT2yXj2foRWz9hBpiXHwRksmaJ8FtKcYn52UzOsnYx3PHK2auHEEmUSOFhaEM32d781cQfIGSm4pvo1NkMFz94IlIJgMTErnfQ2YOlqEFWiSvZOsOC@ZLSqjww9U1JSDgwO3j1Y7nanWDy5KPdO1g6A6udUJfUi2cw4UtKsAJfphkFauo8hH4Qprdvgmtyd72sjcpoh1lTLZVqALtKEg0lh/skvkcLcFGaabTh@X7JNkX6YG0bPzrYr5xRivQDak5R/g2NyT1rPchZIkczolywf6Q2yb6XZUiuclgDzmuYdNtLOCBooKaQj@00@K3RBF0j2jFE9Llrvma9wVH8IXcEUFeVVfx7/PHL4z0AvUkOc66IhscCcwsQu67qsuaAlRvEPGlvgcmH1dgtVCAeybZCnJsiHJtpsx0lIEld3AjDSooiRZAZ3i2VEoImUFy3I3OQxHhWqgGZjCWgS1jU1gXP2NQcFeBxIje6yIxYsqf0b9gO2do3jrISOVRvNwGqK4PYzaMbbAJHMc97erTkQDoagyrFTXcblXsbizIj7LvV0UgfTKVoyM4ovmZtQLkuA3GyKAXqOpKeEEOvTRRdEtxDgWGsdNBjjfJ4HjFOKjhzU30C7hPuL2CFwQGEqRcLElylX9H3wiYA3lKzjur6HVoeJZ2KoT0kCfb43wLwN9krn9YEaZP7EwgZ7cB3sv0CdRuDyG1Vt@ppsXoT4LXUc7qoW85xV8aoy1cPg/l1YtrvyIrq2haDQIzAhvf7@x6Tc)

Here you have the [verbose version of the code](https://tio.run/##hRT9T9s49Hf@ireIKnZx7FHKxsGYhradjmm9ToWdmC5XN7QueJQEmrTb1DT/eu89O2WFnXTPepbf95ft4XUyHWbJZLXqzCaF/TS1acHaz/nRlj8evsu@pSKQwRMO7L1ETiebG3b4@a5nr66LB41ze2tytvebCHTAkdsz44kZFt25mU6SO4accTYF1mpzWGwBnOS5vUrZ7zYdseDy/nqSjG8KMx9@zb5d3dnvMB3d5rM0ECfFaToy39mlsJwLMOjnwfjcTNNk@oO9v58lk5y19lBHtF6InR22@xy1E6f8YXZ7d57V@XWy0WySMSP2udhFBM8@TYt3dm5HxktecmfpCt0TLUf4Kn1P1lSycd7s2WMe7P/0hm37aMbFpg7R6zw6Np3lLMGQ6zYC2DGwjybPmRVvk7xg95z7FtYu/zRXSWHYLhf1qe3tHiXhZiV2fxWss/uP/B70PE9AEMfBU8kT@/aTGB0cPWFbnIxGj2dgxQF1Wnjm/guncVOTbfFzJKToQJxN7NCwACRowlCDhx23y36Gu2aYJAl06sXbXkfStozjrloAB9aXfRSrKo6RzcKjEHnOKUcSPZB2KUp0oxXEsdawVM04XuBZqvlgHqJtk6wXcVzulGoJCg5RCK8ZZMBfoTUuGFBYicrNZpNCZd0DAGdaOXoUXWI8H4IzlANwqUtcEpTsS9LBra/Ij0bATR4fC8xdNh3Po3RLe6iZr6LXGSIo3dCqjKLy4qKMMLhzyrpwAV0urcYl9Ve3GFBhHEI1j@MBUBpUBW5US6kjOinoU51lVFVRheJSE9f1UdXz8JYKC0MIgckoiyRHHeWwdFmSxvZ2Sbn@5a2st0Wn6EqFA@ezPKYhLJRDgYymm2bk5nnpzmEjJMo1XCmJQJbK50SdVe6KSHdPlBrwI7QJ0absV5V04b6Qfck44@iFNbhLoes9SAgRGw1ytmge41rqUGpJ109T/tiCv/@hTlFV8EZroWKEyoOqu@JMIBBwI8BfdfxmNt/OwS8PmJ7@5ufG17@Q91jFKW7Qed/rfSGigrd/9E7PzjsnZ8@8EMUE/tUuERebr7d@1Vr/36ve@Jbaj1W9i57BXz43zP1P@PtaXle23FquVq32Kpr/Cw), quite understandable. My approach is the opposite from @Neil's. He draws all the gifts and then covers those not needed. I only draw the gifts needed.

- 5 bytes saved thanks to Neil!

Comment: Save 3 bytes: `Print(Map(Map(4,Add(Times(Modulo(i,8),7),Times(56,Add(k,Times(4,IntDivide(i,8)))))),Slice("`...`",k,Add(k,7))));` instead of the `for (4)` loop.

Comment: @Neil I understand your code and it seems a good idea, but I cannot get it to work on TIO.

Comment: Don't try to copy/paste it; Stack Exchange inserts zero-width characters into comments.

Comment: @Neil That must be the reason, because when I wrote the code myself suddenly it started to work. :-)

Comment: Oh, it's a 5 byte saving? My fault for trusting Charcoal's `l` option...

Answer (score 40):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 666 bytes

```
Ｊ⁶³¦³⁰←×⁷⁷_↑³⁶.→⁷⁷↓.↓³⁶↖Ｊ±⁷±⁴”}➙◧﹪ε⎆Ｔ⎆¿⊘W？⁸ω⁷{↙n,θ<YθＴＬＵeK%I(+↥Ｃ…hχRνGζ)ητＲ✳⮌⁹πj,⊞Ｒ∕!lD)CN✳χＧ-=ê⊕l⟧ＲＰ↙§m∧Ｅ⁴Ｆ≧GＷ!↨⪪⟧⟦⟦Ｘ=G﹪ς←´:¦B^⟲⊟H⌀SM⦃}´↶E$zfI⮌εÞ⁶ι⟦⁺～Ｗ]ＸιθＺ¦@|θ⦃‴1₂↑dＡ=÷ＰＴι^V⪪Ｎa÷⌈b#lＱ+;BＴ⟲⌀6↑↥\⁺◨ⅉ8'Àq；？.6μ″D⎇Ｍ3§ν⁻φＧ>2Σ¿⟧u←@6nh¹⮌↧,‴¹f↧M⁵|Dυχ¶3⊘>γＱ·UB×NO³{Ｌκ3¤³ν⊕φβ.¤+xl⁷MΠ⦄η+L➙⁺[Dσ◧；≔e=F⊘ξρHλκＬ`Ｓ"d｜N℅⊗0§χ～vＨ⍘À§⊕g↖c@Π]R¦⎆πＥx⁶⪪~;⸿j}⊗⊙↷A‹›N·？ＣＸ[´m'Ｊχ0`-⪫νd⪫⎆/Ｍ⍘ζＧ＆Ｇ⟲Ｆ¿Ｇ⍘×.#ςςm≧ω²Ｅⅉmv`⊞ω9Þ·'ＺNN→Ｊ＆γQ«T～_J6◨z⪫ＯＢg¤upε↷~⁵T«P{Ｚr»λ≔u⧴⁰ⅈ｜≕q⊕≔χz⮌…@ＭυA➙⭆/TLＦ}¤Ｎ*Ｎ⁰⁶↖¬∕κE>α;|Ｗ"h↙⊘⁹}Σ1⁰g⮌ＦRü0ＡÀ⊗"⁸$”Ｆ⁵Ｆ⁵«Ｊ×¹⁵ι×⁷κ←×¹¹_↑⁵.¹¹↓.↓⁵»Ｆ²³«Ｊ×¹⁵Ｉ§”o⊞O↧▷⁰$ê;”¦ι×⁷Ｉ§”o⊞-Y~Ｆι,]”¦ι¿‹ιＩθ«Ｍχ←↓ →\↑⁵← \»«↖ＵＯ±⁷±⁴ ←←⮌Ｉ⊕ι»»Ｊ³⁴¦¹⁷↓  H ←____↗↑ ~  ⁴¿‹²³Ｉθ«Ｊ²⁰¦¹⁷↘¹↓⁵↖↑\ »«Ｊ⁴⁴¦²⁰ＵＯ±²²±⁴ ← 42
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVZ/b9s2EP3b/RQ3wY4oRSL1KzWQ1cOKbkBTNHPhpliKsuHSVEmNJlJru@mA0PrqHknJ4tHxKBD2kbynd488nq6@XC6u6svbzebVj7tvZzV5mkeQJ8GvT94s5tWKHL8ur1cRnM3vyiUZjyPwhBfY2Xff1Oqnve1Rz87N5jdflOt4bIf@qH9WCgKvaocMxml9X2pI/UpldoT@Km8uVyUZBxF0fwtLwAMKQvW@Meb7nANqFBsgVEMGnUwiwStYcz5lDwiFqmZxhGDAOfJkYiSY3FpxLM/PZaxxWMi5xZGSBCTo1/2juVC/nxXqAWnpqL9SgbAwDFEMUooPH4VdxugFxdMahfUm0RH6vGofA@sIMHQs2UikzQMz3SqnHo1BfepPkVMkHQxwTKUTQ@rPhXo0ClO8nJ3Z8YP3jsWmgIOMmyZulDgmPBH08Dp4gbZYWdb4XYiIcW5xpPGWVh1RYXUE4V4gEEGtXU@S/k1Nt/MTvVugnQDpr49kYDHIMLAYMpSm2zBVlLz6jUANwTM0euxEr1T1oP5fFElGgdYGFAoElok5tIjKZDKxVPxT33SsjVVGOAdHc5lo760UB6PhYbiVooHdprNJ8ZnCOUwDO6ibVMmyHQmZzz2VrgcG5PTP2ey9A/YBPqrN1WcHLrAevG8Wa8g5FZSNFMCLl7OTt2enz9/@YtHanQ8UFufM9Mdg@KT4o4PwcNiq0@jmxBebhrPsEE9HOjY3RZwbKXTvpLlGYA1OjkOdfQiT@r6PnRh1Uon6I9/o1ISNOwG@vQAfwol61mjHY3StyIumoTrFNEiDLqCmcQXwlc722BAa1zHtN1mYWXWl6iv@ul4AOQpg@/vwZNBd6m09SY8imAd9dYngq77ZB3sqT5r2lWeASs@Rtdui0hlpihbiouOOafd1yzLL99N7cblckeerk@pz@S/xiiRJ8qTI0jTN0yJLVM/yIvd0GAEOxHVLkqxI0yzJszQpiixP8iIt0qxz07Tm10Bel8slmXe@39W4JjQwRTFNIjjuyuJgJy7w8GBXdD3OneFeLFdcD7p1ayhvl6V9oa3Cg8H0021d3eytw/b1rdcuxfYts/K@XCxLYgI7qa4W5V1ZrcrPZBv9Wu1Cp3xeRJA@/mIAeAne7keJp1PaQx8OJnj348TTV4D1LNS/Xuss3xG745AlHQesdCdsuvcQPRINM1CZpAlYibvXFCrUTH9p7SicZXsl3tm4IjOgm01WbOL72/8A) Link is to verbose version of code. Not really golfed, but I'm not sure I want to...

```
Ｊ²⁵¦³⁰←×_³⁸↑³⁶.→³⁸‖ＯＦ²⁴«Ｊ×Ｉ§”o⊞∧№qＧo⁴↨'”¦ι¹⁵×Ｉ§”o⊞Þ‹wα≕ＹＱ”¦ι⁷≔⎇⁼²³ι²⁶⊕χη←×_η↑⁵.η↓.↓⁵↑¿‹ιＩθ«Ｍη← ¶\↑⁵← \Ｍ⁴→…⪪✂”}⊞μ↓↙Ｊ∧W⎚2⁻⁹]jι｜T◨%êⅈπ↔{Mⅈ⎇_u9⁹F⪫4ＡＧhd⪫ＣNb↷a^ＡnQ⌀oV←×⟦c″⁵FιＯ↗ωsＸςb⁶β|(α)ⅈ,gＢ№$¹ξU=◨↷…Yn´;⎆Σd$=1%▷≦″“}υ⌈ν§Ｖ？Ｗξ⌈‖⦃⊗↓⎚Ｋ⎚✳Ｖ✳V？↗⎆¶﹪⊙⟦≧*(▶″$Q；\⟲↶A⊗s≧»Πj⁸⎆↑´T≡⁵Ｋ⊙αηI3⊙✂“↗⌕Ｎ~e%⬤Ｉη◨γ·y⁸_Gλ↙%ＥＯ)⎆$YＰ“¦7ê⁵№¹▷⟦α)ν&℅◨⦄Ｓ“⁹aEＸ>➙8)↨§+φ✳⁸WＲ&；⎚◧⎆¬▶B³u▷J±÷δ+⁺↖Ｍ≧；↧χw➙Oθ✂⁺⁶r⟦ＧεCVY↖<⁻◧⁹ＤＫ‴1⌀✂$k\φ{0·M℅,ρ)S⎇⸿3oψＪ5$\`↗⁰⊙0c¤?&？⌕↗Ｕε¦⎆～b＆d⊞÷f¬；Ｔ-χＵnν⁶{⊖″;f._⟦#⊗V2⍘¬T.(⁻<Ｖ⊗№êx⊕₂⦃ΣσＧτ¹yΣ2⁶⧴em⁷ＷÀI>]≔A↘_2↓⁴⸿¦y⌕ⅉ﹪B7”×ι²⁸φ¹⁻η⁴¦⁴»«↖←←←⮌Ｉ⊕ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVRtb9MwEP68/oojahcnS@y8DRCjiAmQGKIq6oY2NG@m6lwaKUtG0w3QvPz1cr50bfdhZyVn3/tzlm8yG88n1bhYLr/cXt@cVCzZDyCNvIPOt3leLtibr3q6COAkv9Y1c5SDytfeRvv9BgUv12eHOxvdKP81W5D9QWekp4WeLIZ3el6MbxhKptUcWJJ5cN/ZWaVuk3wY1wt2uDgqr/Rf5mRRFKVRlsRxnMZZEuGXpFmaYiG55wUQ73uP1T11jKIki@MkSpM4yrIkjdIszuJk7fjKotg5rOv8V8lO9Lwcz/@xT79vx0XNktQaBZC8DOConMz1tS4X@orFEQpn1u@55sy8La1tzv7m3DZnddiO8rH6UwbwRL2SkfegutM2mN3nU2BfdV2zPADC@9vzqIWt1SwAqsmaPmYFWUrpbEk2dT2FgZYrO4qVYSy6wi3LQVVcseObIl@w4yKfaASteL8fqDA0Z2cmBGUADDCF5AJwUPjBg5RDcY9c@FIiF76PGwBQpcI/MEwL8I5BBd5bBsgAz7BndSAaMhWNbzeWNeis7gXYD0tWgsyGuIX3SgVCSvIAis1d7g5BYD0opLoUxjZ9Q05Alob1PFs36kjMrbOySqV@cgoCgl9yNLb2fSRJZBC2XNP2nmpQFpjCrLYRHmZ7A1QERbYIu4TQBJTV4AKuDC5u8yusX6ieEsaKUEsMwQZo7NvucGoRBxd40xIe8xZ1z@VgLpuGN0a5XHHXQsOIBm@n61kG0oEKOaLBzIoaxoZwBkNb6iVBlVLQB0K4rm2/4EgI3DCPeQZLOr@wge0FA5zDha3dtF0OiVxCRiW5WNK938f1AFSSVTUb7Eg/6I84ycPndEm8vSQVYibGwyrkHoKmlStc3IRNEzamzWv4KSpOufExqG9WzB24gB/f7XX32rBIzYr7wpUOwtsl2eDTaPSDdF0psUzRw8OHz6Oj45PB4fELaNzerr/XddsQq64DOI9zAF9m8hrnxBSHE7JBXt7W9mFmdupkNB8eQBe13jxbfJHrV9sKnjs@ebAjjeO01u3g255TOODaPJ2H5TLJluFd8R8) Link is to verbose version of code. This is a version that draws the presents separately for <s>577</s> <s>541</s> 530 bytes after I've stolen several ideas from @Charlie to golf a few more bytes off.

Comment: Satan Clause is coming to town.

Comment: Don't worry, I also borrowed a couple of ideas from you, so we're even. :-)

Answer (score 24):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>1322</s> <s>1319</s> <s>1287</s> <s>1265</s> <s>1061</s> <s>1059</s> <s>1056</s> <s>1032</s> 1030 bytes

```python
n=input();k=' '
print'.'+'-'*77+'.'
for l in'','','\n','	','\r':
 for L in zip(*[['| ']*7]+[['.'+'-'*q+'. ']+['|'+[(['\  ']+[' | ']*6)[j]+"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".decode('base64').decode('zip').split('Q')[i-1].split('U')[j],k*(q-4)+'%2s '%(`i`*(j>2))][i>n]+' | 'for j in 0,1,2,3]+[['| |'+'_'*e+'| ','|'+'_'*q+'| '][i>n],[' \|',k*3][i>n]+k*q]for i in map(ord,l)for(q,e)in[[11,26,9,24][i>23::2]]]):print k.join(L),'|'
print'|'+'_'*77+'|'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVPpb@JGHFXvblq13XZ7fLRWWo3NODHY2IZUWYlwxhhjDgcHYnV94gtf4AMr/3tqWNpP83u/mfeeRnovOh7sMCBfX4M7J4jSA4r97d0BBFxFiRMcwA2A4BrUWBZW45UVJoiPOAH48u33P34BcPDtD@@@@aM6v3oOfv7zu2r45c1fv1bH18/Jb7//BG6vkBOFryhI6URobbMBLwhQaqwCq/EiHlfa1RJWdwBu0A14Rj5D5PyWwTauAt@bXCFI3iAdlv0JMQnr8XhgkFJm7Nio05/Pw15d20YP4XLeGwohp@vkoWD26pgy6irb7Ud2vngcRQ9Pbm528jV/fGSoxWrJjh6iwnbzOZuLOTscdukhdFo92R3AciuGE7NZ7Iy9RwnqzppNpsP7lcV79CybNyyzpPX7VBMjlU5MR4QqFa7YtEyOD8ITnNhla@YPdIkr2lsdhlHbEiiZ9HpmJnc13R5lFkvsvGOHZ0lhsCPcpdA8HkRBTcejlWrtRybFypprrpOYkEljErrHDkeLXeZIZcm4PeUsf5pIpGDI/DgLSlEcjZhVqwPn1nCxLAq7pAnNIsp1SttBqPfXQc7StDCewDgfxmmLtEVLHxl9eZdNDUNfd9aapnEJkVa/6ldGQTpdOUQ4pMKsaVBxm/edpr9l0/V6lzGtA8sRzAPXirm1yszNvd1tEPqxLSZWHvQbTD6ZJ3yduNfme2pS6HxSh7QhrAaxnY0PY8Ls71phlEuD9krmRtR@NvLERu9xETRcyzK2g9ZAJHxyBX1TTYq2OoFBapXECiY8ZPti4BU9@Mj0JMKwaTH2CZcyEoeT9WRBJhRrartQEqSoLvtDhoEUcWwSWsCa2f6eX2RaM@GsRkbAztOyXUqtu/c3hqmHhokCTd2bTBNg/y@quFZoH/nOAQUzgG2c64byH5bAKZO4V0Pj6yYGwQdyj4AP6CfnUw11P5IYpmycj4ECzwk@NcA9NaCON3ASp87Rf0GqrIN/QM2Ep0bg4ALjM/xMx6sGPL@Ayoa66Hm1WDnJOSe5nRqhYWLgPlat0Bg3MSfYbBqVB4O3cbJ54pDU7S2pKAp2e64z4t24oROgPHYyvFT84nyq@At4fW1Q/wI)

-4 bytes thanks to Mr.Xcoder

-24 bytes thanks to Lynn

---

**Compressed version (thanks to Lynn and ovs):**

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>1021</s> <s>1017</s> 1013 bytes

```python
exec'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'.decode('base64').decode('zip')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc/HsqpIAADQz3FeUTV9CTayRFCSQBMkuCM1GUFSy8/fN6vZnt0Zv0v1Hpjf34IU2anQiRUoNGIO0QEz3NZ7@FHl1XZoXQmD3tUbd2xh5cQuLO1HJcW0ZsB93bFb9hvLIjtUEzePaH4gW8MybN8knyOhBvfKF74T6kNGyzP79tzJqW/M@@Jvd/Z8wbAs4BgGYfeYU@hccbkkPJMH6jvrCvDDPPUs8R5RQIuK3RKi6HgTcDfUnK1p8lV@DA4JOIHxbnYRG45g4JduTJMrXd2JVfKgHeh@YB5nS@pNbXrngqffRbB9mfE1cuhaiuQMpK@wWujSR/2qIisziuDtr2401FffHOXS3fvFi@AuxYo/3K1@M4c47R7ymRhQM4dv/BFLocERhGVU7Q/4IthrH0AEDcPH6aJGtwvDedPFvcOkVcyzTmXuQJULweRacZyfUaaMZovZ2Rgf7MrHZqsRWY3GacYEsdw7o@SXJ9ygWtkZBazcmIQj1ffCbb8eL9YiNuQrIhYwyIjkc@MICRNmG@WLKq0REPnchstOBNktRpNuU89iBwsCkZzTAb1fDGgfvj9SxwRDR1aC8ljvFX3Uy9dIsxcZid6qylLRBBwZGaqbZDEQ066DL9eQu0MOdBUWLrJrKw7eolz4b4VZeVjuViG1W33RkV7dCModF1E4NXAjV6AWW9uUd8my/NIcoshFfPEwXqa4fboG6DRrJ7x2rndeGLIzx5iraF/u2T0SXS4Akbnvz4cdb9TAK6wOuHRcZCyzsw8Qf9lu@Td7DtURDcfWlZCuVT/iR@AhZuQO1mA/QWqhF5NHP477E84R7N4cGNifMzg@fIGgEs5bEmzR0Bca8DXhzFo763N9LNEtHQYK@Hbpju2W78LvgV69EeNOi8dy7t@B0bVF16lRoBrsZN24pgG2R0ibOnoOK2no2izNpBo80@zTfJ7PLZ1QvIaLOe@zlDxfwiav9MeL1ORoChRSxstYNj1/IYLXPvwul/VKLL0PcprVvI6keV@EMPSeQ9sguoYEfePZXD8UihqGPv2bF9k7L/45pclcQO7053846vH05/eXZv8C)

Comment: This is extremely impressive. Well done!

Answer (score 23):

## Befunge, <s>1220</s> <s>1198</s> 1186 bytes

```
<v5,,$$_\#!:,#-\#1<,".N-."+55p00&
v>1-:10p:1-!30p7>1-::0`\5`+3+8g40p::6\`\1-!+6+8g50p" |",:,,:530g
>-1-:20p:1-!30g* 35**60p10g5*+9+8g57*-:70p00g`!\6\`*40g,v
|01g07p09!`3%7+5 :p08+*27-\*4/8-1g07:,g05,g8+2`4:,g8!%5:_:2-v
>-8%7*60g7+:!v!:-1\+1,+*g05< v!\$_1#!-#:\:#,<:g05-*3\+9g06:!<
# +%68*+,:,v$_\: 80gg90g*:!^v_70g:55+/:68*+\!88+*-,55
^^<<<<0<<<<>$50>0$#<>#5g#$,#<40g,48*:,,:v>1
"|_M|"+55_^#!:$_^#!,,"|"+55$_>#!:$#g02$#<^v!:\,<
 \| |.- _1860'5;,3#*:2-&9(7.)$/+4%   @,,$$_1-\:^
   +    _(")_   _n_     $      .     ____ __.==,_  |~|
  /~\  (_ . _)  (")    |,|  __/ \__ /_%_/|--|XX|-  | |
 /~*~\  / : \ >( o )<  | |  `.   .'|_|_| | _|  |    Y
/~*~~*\(_/ \_)(  o  )._|_|_. /.^.\ |_|_|/ (____'   _|_
 . . .  _   _    i   _{/ _{/    _     b   \  ====   .-.
.i_i_i.( `v' ) .'%'.   \_/    .'.'O .'''. \\\|+-|  //`);
|-~~-~| \   / |^~~.~|  /O \  /___\ {*=*=*}\\\\\+| %%
|_____|   V   _'._.'_@__,/\\(_____) '._.' \\\\\\\//
  \O/  __/\__  ('v')  \   /    .==.   .;'   ...  .&%$+*.       ~
[ ]|_. \_\/_/ //   \\._o_O_..--'  |  .m_.  '*  ` */'"'\&   ~ MERRY ~
|_____)/_/\_\ |\   /||/\/\/|\_____/ C|  | |_/\*_|$\._./% ~ CHRISTMAS! ~
------'  \/     Y Y  """""""`====='  |__| [_____]'%&*+$'     ~~~~~
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=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&input=MTQ)

Might still be possible to golf this further by compressing the pictures, but that would likely require the use of extended ASCII characters which aren't currently supported on TIO.

Comment: How is Extended ASCII not supported?

Comment: @Zacharý On TIO the Befunge interpreters are configured to use a UTF-8 character set, so if you try to include an extended ASCII character in the source, it will be converted into some multibyte UTF-8 sequence instead.

Comment: Is one of the Befunges you used for the befunge-polyglot answer able to handle extended ascii?

Comment: @Zacharý It's not the interpreter that's the problem - most interpreters can handle extended ASCII just fine. The problem is in the way TIO translates the webpage input before it passes it on to the interpreter.

Comment: I love that the pictures are fully visible in this!

Answer (score 13):

## Python 3 + numpy, 
<s>1164</s> <s>1159</s> <s>1123</s> <s>1103</s> <s>1097</s> <s>1065</s> <s>1061</s> <s>996</s> 994 bytes

Compress all things and use numpy to bind them together.

First build closed doors, then replace the doors that need to be opened. Finally, output everything.

*-22 bytes thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).
-5 bytes thanks to [notjagan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63641/notjagan).*

EDIT: **<1000 bytes!**

```python
import lzma,base64,numpy
def g(i):
 a,b,c=[numpy.array([*map(list,i.split('#'))])for i in lzma.decompress(base64.b85decode('T>t=p0RR90|NsC0{{R;Yb2=9ZB3vrGRZhN&js}K8Jmx>v0UA+%!XNuvypanfw-On6yWAqj;f`A@KhRXYG|EfWG~vnf74-|TMD9O<F~(ETm1ht`IL9PRn$&D6@Y`ipqj|2Ks2<w>M0$9alb)6kEp5V>=}iliy4by-zIAEIDqtxiie`c-6+Y_|0z6A#o^?bVc8rNg(dZq)&RMVNZfUWe9`uW87eke^e(U)p=MxBK<aHfTf^JIaEkVa{$4ct<>U}>seZ>tXR2yYjN4W~W;4T16Lv_gAVbahgLo23$DPcrdfNc#QKNxGKmP}?>l;j`Eqj*EArIMnEHDC^u(JA0-eXP$Dx!}mqnSiX}lV507wtt#)-Y{K8q<bZx*3<UiIyS__cP#9?=eN*+sh{-OgeVPlr}`jFjZnFR5NVI(DC8>d%B9EZ=gGyMp)jVbx#uVGLDHNS8Ht`@nS~?ji$ls${$28WROQ@UlY>?I1yXSuWNx7+$YlLSM2tP^f1Vl92;=q~#2jV2qwZB}$El*yJ9lpEpg5&X=pYfDIT;IHs;wMLzIOhXWsm-1n5J{Afro^Zv~Fw$_ylaND7>_!(y1hiO*la?Xms}*M82nm86zo6Lpf%>K)!16qKK7m8<A!0_88GZtXScr*7YoejPFWfmdKNN&;MKgQUoU')).decode().split(':')]
 if i>23:a[23:27,45:59]=c[:,168:]
 while i:i-=1;h=ord('EAKUIFOCQLGDVYMPBTWHXJNR'[i]);v,u=h//5*7-89,h%5*15+6;a[v:6+v,u-3:u]=b;a[v:4+v,u+1:u+8]=c[:,i*7:i*7+7]
 for i in a:print(''.join(i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVNZd6JoFHzPrzBHEsGtBWVVMCSiIooGFVxOVFSQj7AJuBCjfz1jd8/Mw70PVfdU3YeqIIkt3yv//AA38MM45Xy5en6tRwZRyXsHN0getoaZ2sEAYR5Sdya/Yed/8KIehnoCz7OuHsAOiOI8KEaBA2I4k84gyAdi@mEKpID3R7K4NTa@G4RGFMF/1YtrCv8Nbg04M@JiNigpCl36lqO30uWiVKdrjKVnr@Vj2FJmlvxsR1eJ6rhn7lga87mnx4l8OCaB7pmnQt8jEo3f21Vzxb9IljKZtr4FU2vdjp5JVgrfo16D7teaN1gYuagVr8QuPVA86LlBvExXINjb35gUYbUT1ytBtO6sEeJTCHCVY6/AAUllnRS@RF4QG/v4DICx2hSI3HT5Xfoi@LS/qK/VDRXKO3g72yPPSk@VZ@ZYM@jVQaNI49NYGPAYCdje@VWq6W1zZC46oi58qvoFqmziGje@cpEx4@KJgiVTW65oN61aGaFE97jc8epat3ZdHytDjcEm3JryJv0uyeeW5A6udc6p2ithb2cFPhR7ntBuvC0OcIcvFYzJAGqcH6/u3huCydVR8RJ5iuM0UpheJGpfW8/O2XJtDMRkuFxuBmm6zhpyNhdZl0J/Z6gDJ7yu7KY985oKLqsi3HijuO3TKy3M2F0r6QWIra7P6YPa6jba8pBqx6sXb3ir2wByIugCYZSm9N9fxs6Uq4toMhkeNPlM5qCp0x32sHiwMFHVobEqu7@lMVvF9qfZ6xUSnGzSoZ1ACHb484QNpmZDHFXFdlQ99bpfYt@aaJFbQD28c@HN0F/MjrfmCVomji43SG75CCeoBfpZR69P3Oia7VGY51LEl090A/OJk5BHlNhLEulSNf6xtKSo1iyeDDdhlpz6hj1oaqa7lWT5udqTdu9jf3yPcPHfeCL/5ZrJIB8PKWCmAIeVGX1@XxiZr@AMTn@wmzmTRwmKuV@cLOAYKcCAAotWLdYPt3BG4KWx2Oy/vXdbDXXaG7yOtPakIyuZOfhAqsf8gbV@/cKzZIGi89YTnkXxHFHV50eGyN3JQpk5fLDrP0DlN5BDmUOO@usKsiRznxx5t/6/dDoThMC7P50p2j7w7v1FfnYwijzsYKyCPPz8Aw)

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>1296</s> <s>1291</s> <s>1211</s> <s>1166</s> 1164 bytes

That super-long string, though (59% of the whole thing!). There's gold in them hills; I can feel it.

Edit: If there is gold, I've only found specks so far.

Edit: -2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```c
#define D"BQHLAFKTEVCJOWGPIX@RDMSUN"[p=r*5+c]-64
#define O D<=n
#define P printf(
#define G(x)for(x&&P"  |\n|"),c=0;w=D^24?7:22,c<5;c+=1+(D==24))
#define m(c,n)memset(calloc(n+1,1),c,n)
char*x[]={"_|","\\","33 ","6 ","__",".'","  "," ."},*v,*u;U(char*q){for(;*q;q++)*q>47&*q<56?U(x[*q-48]):(*u++=*q);}t[4],r,c,s,w,p;f(n){P".%s.\n",m(45,77));for(v=u=m(r=0,732),U(".W.7W.|*| |*||*| |*|'M' 'M'_'_3 ) (^.^_1./v`v' oO833+36/~13/~*~1 /~*~~*16.^o3(';') {1|+|/}6d-b3_(\")_ (_7 _) / : 1 (_/ 1_)6_n_3 (\")6>( o )<(6o6)3$36|,|3 | |6.00_.3.34/ 14`.35 /.^.16.1^/. <->o<-> '/v1`23446/_%_/||00 ||00/ 4.==,_--|XX|- 06| (44'3.*.3 /.13|_-0 (.-o-.) _3_ (O X O) / ^ 161/ 1/6.777i_i_i.|-~~-~||4404444j_j_j_ ||_0 0/$$|_ _3_ ( `v' ) 13/3 V33i3 5%'. |^~~.~|_'._5_ 4/142~2 1_1/_/3~ MERRY ~3 /_/1_1 ~ CHRISTMAS! ~31/2~~~~~2|=|3 / 13|(%)|6|4037;'3.m_.6C|6|3|_06,3* +6. +3. '7~~~~~~~3.-.3//`); %%3 //2 b3 5''. {*=*=*} '._536_3 55O /4_1 (44_)");r<5;r++){P"|");G(s=0)P"  .%s.",m(45,w+4));for(;s<4;s++)G(1)sprintf(t,"%d ",D),P"  |%2s %*.*s |",O?s?"|":"\\ ":"",w,w,O?v+p*28+p/18*32+w*s:s^3?"":t);G(1)P"  |%s%s|",O?" |":"__",m(95,w+2));G(1)P"   %-*s",w+5,O?"\\|":"");P"  |\n");}P"|%s|",m(95,77));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVRtU@M2EP5cfsXWxVjyi2RZsk3jGHold9xdS0PhOOgQIjgDbTqXV4eEmSj@63QVKJ2eNFpb691Hjzb7pIr@rKqnpx9u7@4HozvoOD///v7XN@9@@fT288HH7vnh8YeLn046R6dnvzmXk3Lmp0F1FWVq69@ELnTa5eh1ewyT2WA0vyevnkPySO/HM/K4s3PsAJjeyDg0rMq4WJadfqL281aShFU7LaqgFAHplGWiKH3NH5IqHNHh3bC@m5Pq5uvXcUVGgQgFguCHreqvm5n/eHlVrhxtnNDp9dBICWgza7RGwzw0YLfAnHXoL0L/oTgjm9wpXVl@hT8tpkFA/emeynf8aTvN9s/I46U/jdTuFW0R/yEISowu1vNLdRXO8Pg6XIaT4p6M6OrYYW7NeiMnHBKVhnlOaWFhF@VDOSSzMg5zmdDwjDjsnOXnzPgGcL08vCMPcGlPS6BA@qyvBeOL64UH4@6ulIHMeCMkb/xGgLWNLzLWH0viFR6FlTCB4evsNvoiNek5VAPROWgKHFogcMNBaJrpEeLb79kegTHQNsnGGZXbMjOhkYBUMhbHmkkmFWaoayZT4KzP8DDR5wza0d4YF3h8Ia4TqVTGtau5MXEM1nBQrCxDHUXm4sJEEGcGiFKeZD6TiCSk0VEMhEXjiFHQEol24QK6lmkfRCbwWJ6xPM8HGiczUdNEjTFKxQrH39pOPErHEPPtbaOfMcBWigJWSMJnKQcSUtdjYPpNwxqjPaZTDYoLlTQJVkJwzWUDR29PTv6ABolpjk5o4OD9yYfTT0dvTr9Ht@BJY0diSiwOEpOGuNRkRsUyL/BOQ82yA9zjpeIslD4EGYNAMvDy5nlIFjHJ@TUtwHURgyfwBbl5yG3llzjXYLnJDH@XNO0CV0gDC6apQ4sZamKGHYm9hZIpDkldxtRqyHbaS58tA/XSaEXdVkWN4YdE0PpFhfPQcW@x7Ts03IjPTWpwfebXgFLp7tf7iNxCyQBaB5t5ic5FMPGT3WDCxa4vk2Dp1626L/cdpzW3JAR9RqrdeoPhgIWwKhuSHy2hhP4XBm7k1wgcpDay17OheJWXPwJ8W@PdNkCb5I1q1k9IHYY3gxGhW6ut7@5JjOWbPMxrYnOtI/3WIdS3nuT/nvXTPw)

### Non-ASCII version

-30 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

GCC on my machine produces something that crashes immediately, making it unlikely that I will pursue this fork. (Not to mention that TiO reckons 1120 bytes for some reason (same as its reported amount of characters).).

```c
#define D"BQHLAFKTEVCJOWGPIX@RDMSUN"[p=r*5+c]-64
#define P printf(
#define G(x)for(x&&P"  |\n|"),c=0;w=D^24?7:22,c<5;c-=~(D==24))
#define m(c,n)memset(calloc(n+1,1),c,n)
char*v,*u;U(char*q){for(;*q;q++)*q<48|*q>55?*u++=*q:U(L"籟\\\x203333‶彟✮†⸠"+*q-48);}t[4],r,c,s,w,p;f(n){P".%s.\n",m(45,77));for(v=u=m(r=0,732),U(".W.7W.|*| |*||*| |*|'M' 'M'_'_3 ) (^.^_1./v`v' oO833+36/~13/~*~1 /~*~~*16.^o3(';') {1|+|/}6d-b3_(\")_ (_7 _) / : 1 (_/ 1_)6_n_3 (\")6>( o )<(6o6)3$36|,|3 | |6.00_.3.34/ 14`.35 /.^.16.1^/. <->o<-> '/v1`23446/_%_/||00 ||00/ 4.==,_--|XX|- 06| (44'3.*.3 /.13|_-0 (.-o-.) _3_ (O X O) / ^ 161/ 1/6.777i_i_i.|-~~-~||4404444j_j_j_ ||_0 0/$$|_ _3_ ( `v' ) 13/3 V33i3 5%'. |^~~.~|_'._5_ 4/142~2 1_1/_/3~ MERRY ~3 /_/1_1 ~ CHRISTMAS! ~31/2~~~~~2|=|3 / 13|(%)|6|4037;'3.m_.6C|6|3|_06,3* +6. +3. '7~~~~~~~3.-.3//`); %%3 //2 b3 5''. {*=*=*} '._536_3 55O /4_1 (44_)");r<5;r++){P"|");G(s=0)P"  .%s.",m(45,w+4));for(;s<4;s++)G(1)sprintf(t,"%d ",D),P"  |%2s %*.*s |",D>n?"":L"|⁜"+!s,w,w,D>n?s^3?"":t:v+p*28+p/18*32+w*s);G(1)P"  |%s%s|",D>n?"__":" |",m(95,w+2));G(1)P"   %-*s",w+5,D>n?"":"\\|");P"  |\n");}P"|%s|",m(95,77));}
```

[Ideone link](https://ideone.com/uNnLdU)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>2798</s> <s>1976</s> <s>1963</s> ... <s>1862</s> <s>1742</s> <s>1703</s> <s>1651</s> <s>1634</s> 1632 bytes

-2 Bytes thanks to ceilingcat

I've replaced a few icons to avoid unnecessary ESC '\' characters.

```c
(*L)()=printf;
#define E else L
#define W"  |"
#define V W" | %.7s "
#define S(x)else if(i<x)L
#define D(x)for(i=0,++j;i++<x;)
#define R L("%s.%1$s.%1$s",I);L(q^7?".%s.%1$s":"%2$s----.%1$s",I,I+3);L(".  |\n|");D(30)d(n)
char*P="_______   +    _(\")_   _n_     $      .     ____ __.==,_  .*.   _   _  . . .  _   _   |~|   //'`\\   |=|   ,   *    j   .&%$+* |  _  | ('v')    .==..W. .W.  ...     .-. _j_j_j_  /~\\  (_ . _)  (\")    |,|  __/ \\__ /_%_/|--|XX|-  /.\\  (O X O).i_i_i.( `v' )  | |  //....\\  / \\  +  . +  .'''. */'\"'\\&| ($) |//   \\\\.--'  ||*| |*| '*  `   //`); ||__|  /~*~\\  / : \\ >( o )<  | |  `.   .'|_|_| | _|  |  |_-_|  / ^ \\ |-~~-~| \\   /    Y   ||()()| |(%)|   . ' .{*=*=*}$\\._./%|  \" o||\\   /|\\_____/|*| |*||_/\\*_| %%    _|/$$|_/~*~~*\\(_/ \\_)(  o  )._|_|_. /.^.\\ |_|_|/ (____' (.-o-.) \\/ \\/ |_____|   V     _|_  ||_[]_| |___| ~~~~~~~ '._.' '%&*+$'| === |  Y Y  `=====''M' 'M'[_____]//     CRIMBGLUFWDKPXHQJYASENTVO",*I="  .-----------",*T="_________";q,i,j,k,l,g;d(o){l=(i-1)%5+j*5;k=7*l+168+168*(i>10)-(g=7*(l>17));if(q=P[672+l]-65)if(q>o)if(q^24)if(i<16)L(W"%9c"W,32);S(21)(W"%10d |",q);S(26)(W"_%s_|",T);E("%15c",32);S(16)(W"%26c|",32);S(21)(W"%25d |",q);S(26)(W"%s%1$s%s|",T,T+1);E("%30c",32);else if(q^24)if(i<6)L(W"\\%9.7s |",P+7*l-g);S(16)(V"|",P+k);S(21)(V"|",P+7*l+504-g);S(26)(W" |%s|",T);E("   \\|%10c",32);S(6)(W"\\%9.7s %7c%9c",P+7*l,'~','|');S(11)(V"%s"W,P+k,"  ~ MERRY ~  ");S(16)(V"%s |",P+k,"~ CHRISTMAS! ~");S(21)(V"%9.7s    "W,P+7*l+504,P+608);S(26)(W" |%s%1$s%s|",T,T+3);E("   \\|%25c",32);i%5||L(W"\n|");}f(n){L(".");D(77)L("-");L(".\n|",j=-1);R;R;R;R;R;D(77)L("_");L("|");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVRrVxs3EP1c/4qpYiFpH1qvie0kyzonDbRxaxdqKI/DgpxjY7LGtQMmHM5B7F@nM1o/SkdIRqOZe69GWg3D6@Hw5U0@G05/jK5gZ3E/yuf6W/tFel0lVfr9Lp/dj5PKm9HVOJ9dwR5cTRdX0F07ThiAZevpMTkscN1awMZ7KB@Vy8vHMt95VJv0XVwZz@9kntYC358kue/vPCZqvd6HrmR8oXlcLQcWdFTSlbeXrY9MLxfYB8br1UWItooJOv42xTGN8rKZZSrZlds1NZIzVRl@@3rnHaTMlAYAPnYwMmOKZmZGI0DVjaDd6CKN0Wka4Kr2yGvKrl1bzcAWFscoEoMso2lK0wC7RzgTQtziVd/DOlG8BSkehHJMaar1CYJhB61LYh1qMBPXELUgTGmQz2AKKaYYGxCWiSDLUGVkuIlsGNrTUxtijnY5@3AK@0rnBpuWMHgQoIjdklYkc1GE4Mqh3SCE0OBFImMiy7ZQaVWBjSJkzNB0GApEsB6CYBe4v4Hb@UAl6DaGoAuvKIE/EHRbwhzUzpJ3QDvUwhpsOKd4@jOhy4RLyrBhUYRYUVdLYoYz2rCVeD0xSXJl3RkJ0E9eiu25isqMjjj6MwZza8tUS7VBi5Z6rYmyzEMmzt352qhaRR/qLbwsk2UxlQQUDEqTRKOxlpdUJ6c4wnNAEyB1OA@1wvjIdet4SNZxeXUsHbM15xe0TbdUlAYClQoQfMvzq8JCmqZUgTPa4yAlE6KH6z1x7jAvXO0BPvc7vV9@6/7968nuHwenX/76/ezT4d6fR8f7LPA6KaNLszH0Ha0vuzEsuQ3yYBLcBNPgOhnJuXqapjIPY8Ub/sRrJDdpy5v6cfMddU/m7bimQnmNXjltxy2lEvyMb9OD82ar7k8vwmZDkaM9dz@X9bfKfeZxU3XlCePvh@wk2K6r5FDWY0WeuDbCNyO4da4muQxfGPQcqWQPP/e4MWTLjNgt83pzaNlrkHrj/yB8QR8/XxBQcOTHJdh2bQm2eoA2CkuBWcbf03OFaQc@7jy8XhEfM@e7WbEu51SdRu1tGVdSgy1pHaX7Oizucr0LF7Pi4a0h1aQECkQhAmGFo3QUfIHlQtIAcQro7fX7Z/gLbCOKL7ViSAGfv/Q7h0e9T4c/Q8E2QksqNAe2VIz/NWvvXqt@VbLt/@qvr04h5w1rXaXcO/o8xjf0iZ5W96i2WlhFFrLytaWQYJLiZUr667YKMmWQA3n552s@k8PgQbnX2HtIKk@Vn8YSzyb5/uN@IRlGVWBpY4nuyvPLvw)

Comment: I don't know if it'll cost you any bytes, but the images aren't quite in the right position within the windows...

Comment: @DomHastings Thanks, I hadn't noticed it.  It's fixed now.

Comment: @ceilingcat That's a really neat trick.  I like it a lot.

Comment: [1576 bytes](https://ideone.com/hS5sXt)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 966 bytes

```ruby
->n{a=%w{8. 99|/ 99|1 8' .;.. |//| |// |=_ 9.W. 9|*| 9|*| 9'M' _99| $)9| "9o| ==9| ~| 9| Y9 |__ .9. i_i. ~8~| ___| $ ,| 9| _|_. ^/. o<8> v1` 9 _9. O/{ *1{ **1 n_ ") o9)< o99) v') 9911 99/| 9Y *. .1 8_| o8.) _.8 +. W9) "` 993 _O_. /1/| """" + ~1 *~1 ~451 . 91__ 99.' ^.1 =| 91 %)| __| ")_ .9_) :91 91_) 99_ X9O) ^91 91/ 99_ v'9) 99/ V ^o ;') +|/} 8b b ''. *=*} _.' i9 %'. ~2~| _.'_}
b=(0..34).map{?|+" "*77+?|}
96.times{|i|z="EAKUIFOCQLGDVYMPBTWHXJNR"[j=i/4].ord-65;y=z/5*7
t=j<n
b[l=1+y+k=i%4][x=z%5*15+3]=b[l][x+12+m=i/92*15]=?|
b[y+(k+4)%7][x,13+m]=["|%*d  |"%[9+m,j+1],(t ?"| |":?|).ljust(12+m,?_)+?|,(t ?" \\|":"").ljust(13+m),?.+?-*(11+m)+?.][k]
w=i>91?["~%14s"%".-. ","~ MERRY ~     //`);","~ CHRISTMAS! ~ %%    ","~~~~~     %-6s "%"//  "][k].rjust(24):(a[i][1,3].reverse.tr("1/;o)8~`></1{)O3451')/bo}~2"[j,5],"/1, (~8'<>1/}(o1*~/`(1d.{^~"[j,5])+a[i]).center(9)
t&&b[l][x+1,11+m]="\\  | | |"[k*2,2]+w.tr('1345298','\\\\/~*. -')}
puts ?.+?-*77+?.,b,?|+?_*77+?|}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVJrU9s6EP2eX7HV1LVlOavKScAiUTy0t/f2RdPSB2UcR5CSzhga3EkCXIjiv05Xoe16tGOdPTo62tnF1fT2/ru5bw8v16cmuFlnCFo76ZOCLATsI4KT0vkEzljQeEQcF7vfKTwIwRIdHnNKTNcOjKG/xhPgWIOzFlAjVLZCaDLCrbVEh2TLsM4iTCRCPciGcK1OQJMewkiuIVa0YgWXFhiHWvMBJc3hOuTkUClK5EwfQ4yA5Jdk6ww5WMxAIBwRlZGe7oAd0S1SEZtRgIBGQUyr6fYU0HsUmdQaQ5iQjiFNBQH3TukA9/4thz0CieivtvBVjzhMtojcAteh9hUJX2BSQ58cCic3kE1hCmGIEJt4Q8ZCqDQEtG9S3wkM7aY1NdFTxE6X4/z05zp3ggGLd3dF7jYtvYOraj5brl3l7gx7sf/m86t/R88/vP3vny/HB@@ffTp6@fX1u0NWnJtKdkusF2ftnV7/1tzJXrzbWpnzwWVrWvwwStyKC1MF3bL439wFvVj1RKc0VCJAqFTMSUCnBJcmd3TkVkQXosuDXaonqiPmpSmYC@IzAMeCQot5ci5UmUQryBnNB9vLHccf51fLVeTlktxyesJDHcZjIjD2l0B6PMlR5O04Uoo2IseyuChbN6YaapUXrAlUd8kChm0ElrAGDl4cHh5DAz6kPOH9Lfr85eGrj58O9j8@olIQ@KLHfWyZQXtnCSRD4wvM34CLrYO0y/ei06IqC5V0CJxdzxbLGa4WEVOyX/OsORkOpFrzUYdmJORyWm@alPqc9MqESZVA1GThYKjkJqpV3MiTSJ3hetI8ULjw2hy/zS5Xs0WkeWv15MmfZif@xaVh4zH10n@suIjTJC3FjTcQKroy1VmYhGMK2dB4t0O@af28Wi3hoWl@PDCZJjQtuf09LPffi7Rb3v8C)

More golfed, but harder to see the pictures in the code.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 974 bytes

This is a function, to be assigned to a variable such as `f` and called as `f[n]`. It prints to stdout.

Turned out longer than expected. I think there are a few more bytes to squeeze out by laying out the picture data differently, which I will try later.

I use symmetrical or near symmetrical pictures, and only the righthand half is found in the code. The left half may have up to 5 character subsitutions compared to the right. The code for making the substitutions is quite long, which partially negates the compression. Only about 60 bytes are saved.

```ruby
->n{a=%q[8.
  |/
  |1
8'
.;..
|//|
|//
|=_
 .W.
 |*|
 |*|
 'M'
_  |
$) |
" o|
== |
~|
 |
Y 
|__
. .
i_i.
~8~|
___|
$
,|
 |
_|_.
^/.
o<8>
v1`
 
_ .
O/{
*1{
**1
n_
")
o )<
o  )
v')
  11
  /|
 Y
*.
.1
8_|
o8.)
_.8
+.
W )
"`
  3
_O_.
/1/|
""""
+
~1
*~1
~451
.
 1__
  .'
^.1
=|
 1
%)|
__|
")_
. _)
: 1
 1_)
  _
X O)
^ 1
 1/
  _
v' )
  /
V
^o
;')
+|/}
8b
b
''.
*=*}
_.'
i 
%'.
~2~|
_.'_].split($/)
b=(0..34).map{?|+" "*77+?|}
96.times{|i|z="EAKUIFOCQLGDVYMPBTWHXJNR"[j=i/4].ord-65;y=z/5*7
t=j<n
b[l=1+y+k=i%4][x=z%5*15+3]=b[l][x+12+m=i/92*15]=?|
b[y+(k+4)%7][x,13+m]=["|%*d  |"%[9+m,j+1],(t ?"| |":?|).ljust(12+m,?_)+?|,(t ?" \\|":"").ljust(13+m),?.+?-*(11+m)+?.][k]
w=i>91?["~%14s"%".-. ","~ MERRY ~     //`);","~ CHRISTMAS! ~ %%    ","~~~~~     %-6s "%"//  "][k].rjust(24):(a[i][1,3].reverse.tr("1/;o)8~`></1{)O3451')/bo}~2"[j,5],"/1, (~8'<>1/}(o1*~/`(1d.{^~"[j,5])+a[i]).tr('134528','\\\\/~*.-').center(9)
t&&b[l][x+1,11+m]="\\  | | |"[k*2,2]+w}
puts ?.+?-*77+?.,b,?|+?_*77+?|}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVL9U9s4EP19/wqdpq4ty1md8gEOieLh@n13NC3tlTKOI0hJZwwE08TQgyj@1@kqtJVHO9bbp6en1S5vZncPX81Da3S1PjXBtzxFYMwpHzSkIeAAEZxSzgdwxgLDI@K42P0M4UEIlujwRFDgrHJgDP01ngDHDJy1gAyhtCVCkxJurSU6JFuGdRZhqhCqYTqCW30CjPQQxmoNsaYZa7iywAVUTAwpMAG3oSCHWlMgZ@wYYgQkvyRbpSjAYgoS4YionPRYB@yYTlGa2JwGSGg0xDSbbk8D3UeTScYwhCnpGNLUEAjvlDYI798K2COQiP5oC5/ZWMB0i6gtcBsyn1HwCaYVDMihdGoD6QxmEIYIsYk3ZCyEkkFA66btK4GhLXB1fVnW0RMlYGaiPxE7XYGL0@t15iRnPN7dlZnbQH8H63IxX61d6e4Nf7H/z39vXo6fvf/31fNPxwfv/vp49Prz328PeX5uStUtsFqetXZ6gztzr3rxLtTmfHgFs/zSaHknL0wZdIv8f3Mf9GLdk53CUIoAqdtyQQL9NsGFyRxtuZPRheyKYJfyie7IRWFy7oL4jJ6dB3lfLpJzqYskqlnGHWF7mRN4eX6zqiMvl2RW0BUe82wyIQLnvwmkJ5IMZdaKI61pITMs8osCvpty1NdZzptAd1c84NhCxhPesIMXh4fHrGF@KHUiBlv02evDNx8@Hux/@INSQeCTHvdjywxaOytGMkpRwp@Ay62DdlfsRad5WeQ66RA4v50vV3OslxHXalCJtDkZDZVei3GHuiUUalZtmjbVOekVCVc6YVGThsORVpuo0nGjTiJ9hutp80gR0msLrxdqUminYRJOaKgmxlYo8Mv8qp4vo76A@unTX6@Q@FIUhk8mVGT/8fwibiftQn7fwPVNvWKPJfPNgcksoV7J7M9Wefiad4uHHw)

Comment: Nice! It was my intention for the picture choices to be the focus of golfing!

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org), 1530

[Try it out](https://repl.it/@BrianGregg/AlarmedIroncladAustralianfurseal)

The clojure solution probably could be a little shorter, but here's my first attempt.

```
(defn a[x](let[k clojure.string/join b" . _ .  }\\O/{  }/*\\{  /***\\  _'_    ) (^.^ \\./v`v  oO8     +     /~\\   /~*~\\ /~*~~*\\  .^o   (';') {\\|+|/}  d-b   _(\")_ (_ . _) / : \\ (_/ \\_)  _n_    (\")  >( o )<(  o  )   $     |,|    | |  ._|_|_.   .   __/ \\__`.   .' /.^.\\  .\\^/. <->o<-> '/v\\`          ____  /_%_/||_|_| ||_|_|/ __.==,_--|XX|- _|  | (____'   .*.    /.\\   |_-_| (.-o-.) _   _ (O X O) / ^ \\  \\/ \\/  . . . .i_i_i.|-~~-~||_____|________j_j_j_ ||__| _|/$$|_ _   _ ( `v' ) \\   /    V      i    .'%'. |^~~.~|_'._.'_  |~|    | |     Y     _|_   //'`\\ //....\\||()()|||_[]_|  |=|    / \\   |(%)|  |___| _{/ _{/  \\_/    /O \\ @__,/\\\\ ,   * +  . +   . ' .~~~~~~~\\  ====\\\\\\|+-|\\\\\\\\\\+|\\\\\\\\\\\\\\   b    .'''. {*=*=*} '._.' " z(fn[n]#(.substring %1(* n %2)(+ (* n %2)n)))i(z 28)j(z 7)s str r #(apply s(repeat %1 %2))m["       ~       ""   ~ MERRY ~   "" ~ CHRISTMAS! ~""     ~~~~~     "] c #(let[w(if(= 24 %)26 11)](concat[(s"."(r w"-")".")](for[i[0 1 2]](s"|"(r w" ")"|"))[(s"|"(r(- w 4)" ")(if(< % 10)" ")%"  |")(s"|"(r w"_")"|")(r(+ w 2)" ")]))o #(let[w(if %2 26 11)](concat[(s"."(r w"-")".")(s"|\\  "(j %1 0)(if %2(m 0))" |")](for[i[1 2 3]](s"| | "(j %1 i)(if %2(m i))" |"))[(s"| |"(r(- w 2)"_")"|")(s" \\|"(r(- w 1)" "))]))d #(if(< x %)(c %)(o(i b(- % 1))(= % 24)))](println(s"."(r 77"-")".\n|  "(->>(for[p[[2,17,8,12,1][6,11,20,5,22][3,10,15,23,7][16,9,24,18][4,13,19,21,14]]](map #(d %1)p))(mapcat #(apply map vector %))(map #(k"  " %))(k"  |\n|  "))"  |\n|"(r 77" ")"|\n""."(r 77"-")"."))))
```

Comment: I wonder if you'd be able to save bytes using run length encoding? I don't know how short the decoding would be, but there are quite a few runs of identical characters...